# Flutter File Picker package is not working at all

Tags: flutter, dart, package, flutter-dependencies

I followed this tutorial online: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LlO5jydXws0

For some reason when I press the button to open a file, it does not work or do anything at all?

Here is my code:

```
ElevatedButton(
                    child: const Text(
                      "+ Select Lights",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      final result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();
                    },
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                        shape:
                            MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                      RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                    )),
```

The usage of file picker in the code is in the first button instance.

I am using an iOS simulator.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Once go through https://github.com/miguelpruivo/flutter_file_picker/wiki/Setup#ios

Comment: I already have all the things it says

Comment: Check if it is working on real device or not

Comment: does it throws any errors?

Comment: I tried it on android and it works perfect, so I think it has to do with the iOS portion of it.

Comment: @Adude Did you find any solution or workaround for this issue?